# jQuery: document.ready is triggered recursively with $.get('script.js') call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery from it's official documenation. I getting acquianted with `$(document).ready`. I have a following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('Document:READY');
  $.get('script.js', function(){
    console.log('Script Loaded');
  });
});
```

What I got from the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) is, document.ready is triggered as soon as the Document Object Model is ready. What I am not able to understand is when I make a load call to `script.js` using `$.get('script.js')`, why it is trigerring `document.ready` again. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVmRhULVpjFA6T27IK9p) and `console.log`

```
Document:READY
script.js:6 Script Loaded
VM562:4 Document:READY
VM562:6 Script Loaded
VM563:4 Document:READY
```

Comment: This is a fixed version of your work...you have a recursion loop, be careful http://plnkr.co/edit/Pz4CUsn83Xtxsr7WoXTv?p=info

Comment: @Hackerman Fix I know I just wanted to know the reason why jQuery triggeres this event. Anyways I got the answer from docs. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is not correct!

Comment: Can you please elaborate the reason why it is happening?

Comment: I wrote same code and it acts correctly [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/23ebRxqcugOF8MbgWioh?p=preview).

Comment: @MohammedElshennawy add script to `script.js`

Comment: add any script or what???????

Comment: are you sure you are not referencing the `script.js`

 in the html and doing a 

`$.get('script.js'`

 at the same time?

Comment: check the [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/23ebRxqcugOF8MbgWioh?p=preview) again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After delving the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), I found that jQuery triggers this event whenever js is loaded dynamically. From api docs:

> scripts can be loaded dynamically long after the page has loaded using
>   methods such as $.getScript(). Although handlers added by .ready()
>   will always be executed in a dynamically loaded script.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get('script.js')` is defined within `script.js`. This means it is recursive, so, in effect you have the `$(document).ready(function()` being called recursive infinite. It never stops calling.